# About angular modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I`m developing app in angular and maybe i having a problem with multiple modules. I have 3 other modules besides the app.module. 
i called them: DashboardModule, InstitutionalModule and SharedModule. 
I imported Shared Module in Institutional Module And DashboardModule. Inside SharedModule i have a TranslateModule but when i compile project with 'ng build --prod' returns an error 'the pipe translate is not found.

Other question i have is, it`s necessary to import shared module in app.module??

Above The Modules code:
App.module.ts

```js
//Angular Core
import { BrowserModule }                                   from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule }                         from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule }                                        from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule }                                from './app.route.module';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader }                from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader }                             from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { CommonModule }                                    from '@angular/common';

//environment 
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

//Guard 
import { AuthGuard } from './guard/auth-guard';

//Pages
import { AppComponent }                       from './app.component';

//Bootstrap components
import { TabsModule }         from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { BsDropdownModule }   from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { ModalModule }        from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { TooltipModule }      from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { ProgressbarModule }  from 'ngx-bootstrap/progressbar';
import { AccordionModule }    from 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion';

//Alert Compomnent
import { ToastrModule }      from 'ngx-toastr';

//Websocket
import { StompConfig, StompService } from '@stomp/ng2-stompjs';

//Modules
import { NgxMaskModule }   from 'ngx-mask';

//Interceptor
import { HttpsRequestInterceptor } from './interceptor/interceptor.module';

//Modules
import { InstitutionalModule } from './modules/institutional/institutional.module';
import { DashboardModule } from './modules/dashboard/dashboard.module';

const stompConfig: StompConfig = {
  url: environment.webSocket,

  headers: {
    login: 'guest',
    passcode: 'guest'
  },

  heartbeat_in: 1000,
  heartbeat_out: 1000,

  reconnect_delay: 2000,

  debug: false
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    InstitutionalModule,
    DashboardModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 1000,
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
      preventDuplicates: true,
    }),
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
    ProgressbarModule.forRoot(),
    AccordionModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard,
              StompService,
              {
                provide: StompConfig,
                useValue: stompConfig
              },
              {
                provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                useClass: HttpsRequestInterceptor,
                multi: true
              }
            ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

Shared Module

```js
import { NgModule }                          from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }                      from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient }                        from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }  from '@angular/forms';

//Translate
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader }  from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader }               from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

//Directive
import { NumberOnlyDirective }     from './directives/number-only.directive';
import { MaskDirective }           from './directives/cpf.directive';
import { KzMaskCurrencyDirective } from './directives/currency.directive';
import { CriptocurrencyDirective } from './directives/criptocurrency.directive';

//Pipes
import { CurrencyValuePipe }  from './pipe/currency.pipe';
import { CpfPipe }            from './pipe/cpf.pipe';
import { CryptocurrencyPipe } from './pipe/cryptocurrency.pipe';

//Dependecies Modules
import { TabsModule }         from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { BsDropdownModule }   from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { ModalModule }        from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { TooltipModule }      from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { ProgressbarModule }  from 'ngx-bootstrap/progressbar';
import { AccordionModule }    from 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion';
import { ClipboardModule }    from 'ngx-clipboard';
import { QRCodeModule }       from 'angularx-qrcode';
import { NgxMaskModule }      from 'ngx-mask';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    NumberOnlyDirective,
    MaskDirective,
    KzMaskCurrencyDirective,
    CurrencyValuePipe,
    CpfPipe,
    CryptocurrencyPipe,
    CriptocurrencyDirective
  ],
  providers:[
    CurrencyValuePipe,
    CryptocurrencyPipe
  ],
  exports: [
    NumberOnlyDirective,
    MaskDirective,
    KzMaskCurrencyDirective,
    CurrencyValuePipe,
    CpfPipe,
    CryptocurrencyPipe,
    CriptocurrencyDirective,
    TranslateModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    TabsModule,
    BsDropdownModule,
    ModalModule,
    TooltipModule,
    ProgressbarModule,
    AccordionModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    QRCodeModule,
    NgxMaskModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

Dashboard Module

```js
import { NgModule }     from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';

//Routes
import { dahsboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard.routing.module';

//Pages
import { AttendancePageComponent }            from './pages/attendance-page/attendance-page.component';
import { CareDetailPageComponent }            from './pages/care-detail/care-detail-page.component';
import { DepositPageComponent }               from './pages/deposit/deposit-page.component';
import { ExtractPageComponent }               from './pages/extract/extract-page.component';
import { HomePageComponent }                  from './pages/home/home-page.component';
import { NotificationPageComponent }          from './pages/notification-page/notification-page.component';
import { RegistryWithdrawUsersPageComponent } from './pages/registry-withdraw-users-page/registry-withdraw-users-page.component';
import { TradeAdvancedPageComponent }         from './pages/trade/trade-advanced/trade-advanced-page.component';
import { SendCriptoPageComponent }            from './pages/transfer/send/send-cripto-page.component';
import { ReceiveCriptoPageComponent }         from './pages/transfer/receive/receive-cripto-page.component';
import { ProfilePageComponent }               from './pages/user/profile/profile-page.component';
import { WalletPageComponent }                from './pages/wallet/wallet-page.component';
import { WithdrawPageComponent }              from './pages/withdraw/withdraw-page.component';

//Components
import { MarketsDoughnutComponent }           from './components/markets-doughnut/markets-doughnut.component';
import { EthereumChartComponent }             from './components/charts/home/ethereum-chart/ethereum-chart.component';
import { LitecoinChartComponent }             from './components/charts/home/litecoin-chart/litecoin-chart.component';
import { BitcoinChartComponent }              from './components/charts/home/bitcoin-chart/bitcoin-chart.component';
import { BitcoincashChartComponent }          from './components/charts/home/bitcoincash-chart/bitcoincash-chart.component';
import { DashChartComponent }                 from './components/charts/home/dash-chart/dash-chart.component';
import { SellBookComponent }                  from './components/offers-book/sell-book/sell-book.component';
import { BuyBookComponent }                   from './components/offers-book/buy-book/buy-book.component';
import { MenuBarComponent }                   from './components/menu-bar/menu-bar.component';
import { WalletVariationComponent }           from './components/wallet-variable/wallet-variation.component';
import { MywalletHomeComponent }              from './components/mywallet-home/mywallet-home.component';
import { BuyTradeComponent }                  from './components/forms/advanced/buy-trade/buy-trade.component';
import { SellTradeComponent }                 from './components/forms/advanced/sell-trade/sell-trade.component';
import { OrdensAbertasComponent }             from './components/ordens/ordens-abertas/ordens-abertas.component';
import { OrdensExcutadasComponent }           from './components/ordens/ordens-excutadas/ordens-excutadas.component';
import { OrdensHistoricoComponent }           from './components/ordens/ordens-historico/ordens-historico.component';
import { BoletaTradeSimpleComponent }         from './components/forms/home/boleta-trade-sample/boleta-trade-simple.component';
import { ExtratoSaqueComponent }              from './components/extrato/extrato-saque/extrato-saque.component';
import { ExtratoDepositoComponent }           from './components/extrato/extrato-deposito/extrato-deposito.component';
import { ExtratoCriptomoedasComponent }       from './components/extrato/extrato-criptomoedas/extrato-criptomoedas.component';
import { PriceVolumeComponent }               from './components/price-volume/price-volume.component';
import { NotificationComponent }              from './components/notification/notification.component';
import { PriceChartComponent }                from './components/price-chart/price-chart.component';
import { SendDocumentModalComponent }         from '../../shared/components/send-document-modal/send-document-modal.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    dahsboardRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AttendancePageComponent,
    CareDetailPageComponent,
    DepositPageComponent,
    ExtractPageComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    NotificationPageComponent,
    RegistryWithdrawUsersPageComponent,
    TradeAdvancedPageComponent,
    SendCriptoPageComponent,
    ReceiveCriptoPageComponent,
    ProfilePageComponent,
    WalletPageComponent,
    WithdrawPageComponent,
    MarketsDoughnutComponent,
    EthereumChartComponent,
    LitecoinChartComponent,
    BitcoinChartComponent,
    BitcoincashChartComponent,
    DashChartComponent,
    SellBookComponent,
    BuyBookComponent,
    MenuBarComponent,
    WalletVariationComponent,
    MywalletHomeComponent,
    BuyTradeComponent,
    SellTradeComponent,
    OrdensAbertasComponent,
    OrdensExcutadasComponent,
    OrdensHistoricoComponent,
    BoletaTradeSimpleComponent,
    ExtratoSaqueComponent,
    ExtratoDepositoComponent,
    ExtratoCriptomoedasComponent,
    PriceVolumeComponent,
    NotificationComponent,
    PriceChartComponent,
    SendDocumentModalComponent
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Institutional Module

```js
import { NgModule }     from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';

//Routes
import { institutionalRoutingModule } from './institutional.routing.module';

//Pages
import { InstitucionalPageComponent } from './pages/institucional-page/institucional-page.component';
import { AboutCoinsPageComponent }    from './pages/about-coins-page/about-coins-page.component';

//Components
import { CoinsListComponent }    from './components/coins-list/coins-list.component';
import { LoginComponent }        from './components/login/login.component';
import { HeaderComponent }       from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent }       from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { RegistroPageComponent } from './pages/registro-page/registro-page.component';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    institutionalRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    InstitucionalPageComponent,
    AboutCoinsPageComponent,
    RegistroPageComponent,
    CoinsListComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ]
})
export class InstitutionalModule { }
```

[image: The error]

Comment: The important part of your code is not shown: is the pipe that provides `| translate` (probably called `TranslatePipe`?) listed in the `declarations[]` and `exports[]` somewhere? Say, in `TranslateModule`?

Comment: Did you try to have the `TranslateModule` module exported instead of imported in your shared module (may need both depending on if other things are using it in your shared module)? If you don't export that then any module that imports the shared module will still need to import that module on its own in order to use that `translate` pipe.

Comment: I think you might be missing the configuration for the shared Module `TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })`